# NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso with phone

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-multidex

I am getting noClassDefFoundError on phones running less than API Version 21. First it was coming with other classes, after removing all the possible codes, it started to coming with Picasso library. I have attached my logcat and build.gradle.

Please help me, I am stucked, I have tried many solution, but no one is working.

Simmilar questions I found are -
https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1264

build.gradle -

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

dexOptions {
    incremental false
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    preDexLibraries = false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kaaryanext.raghukaka"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 25
    versionName "1.2.14"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1') {
exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.0.6'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0"
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0"
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.0'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

> 04-18 09:53:10.990 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka E/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find class 'com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1', referenced from
>   method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso. 04-18 09:53:10.990
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve new-instance 9172 (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso$1;) in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; 04-18 09:53:10.990
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x22 at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Dispatcher;) 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find
>   class referenced in signature (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Cache;) 04-18
>   09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Stats;) 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.squareup.picasso.ResourceRequestHandler', referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso. 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve new-instance 9190
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/ResourceRequestHandler;) in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x22 at 0x001d 04-18 09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain, referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.cancelExistingRequest 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve static method 61383: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Utils;.checkMain
>   ()V 04-18 09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find
>   class referenced in signature (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;) 04-18
>   09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method com.squareup.picasso.Action.isCancelled, referenced
>   from method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction 04-18
>   09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 61214:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;.isCancelled ()Z 04-18 09:53:11.000
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.000 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'com.squareup.picasso.RemoteViewsAction$RemoteViewsTarget', referenced
>   from method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.cancelRequest 04-18
>   09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve new-instance 9184
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/RemoteViewsAction$RemoteViewsTarget;) in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x22 at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Target;) 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain, referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.cancelTag 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve static method 61383: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Utils;.checkMain
>   ()V 04-18 09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find
>   class referenced in signature (Lcom/squareup/picasso/BitmapHunter;)
>   04-18 09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm:
>   Could not find method com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.getAction,
>   referenced from method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete 04-18
>   09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 61218:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/BitmapHunter;.getAction
>   ()Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action; 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/DeferredRequestCreator;) 04-18 09:53:11.010
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find
>   class referenced in signature (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;) 04-18
>   09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could
>   not find method com.squareup.picasso.Action.getTarget, referenced from
>   method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.enqueueAndSubmit 04-18
>   09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve virtual method 61213:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;.getTarget ()Ljava/lang/Object; 04-18
>   09:53:11.010 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Stats.createSnapshot, referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.getSnapshot 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 61376:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Stats;.createSnapshot
>   ()Lcom/squareup/picasso/StatsSnapshot; 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.020 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Cache.clearKeyUri, referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.invalidate 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve interface method 61226:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Cache;.clearKeyUri (Ljava/lang/String;)V 04-18
>   09:53:11.020 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0010 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.dispatchPauseTag, referenced from
>   method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.pauseTag 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 61235:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Dispatcher;.dispatchPauseTag
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;)V 04-18 09:53:11.020
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.squareup.picasso.Cache.get,
>   referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.quickMemoryCacheCheck 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve interface method 61227: Lcom/squareup/picasso/Cache;.get
>   (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap; 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x72 at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;) 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve instance field 34051 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x52 at 0x0001 04-18 09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.dispatchResumeTag, referenced from
>   method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.resumeTag 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 61236:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Dispatcher;.dispatchResumeTag
>   (Ljava/lang/Object;)V 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   I/dalvikvm: Could not find method com.squareup.picasso.Cache.clear,
>   referenced from method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.shutdown 04-18
>   09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   unable to resolve interface method 61225:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Cache;.clear ()V 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x72 at 0x0013 04-18 09:53:11.030 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;) 04-18 09:53:11.030
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Dispatcher.dispatchSubmit, referenced from method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.submit 04-18 09:53:11.040
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to
>   resolve virtual method 61237:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Dispatcher;.dispatchSubmit
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action;)V 04-18 09:53:11.040
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode
>   0x6e at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.040 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Request;) 04-18 09:53:11.040
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$RequestTransformer.transformRequest,
>   referenced from method com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.transformRequest
>   04-18 09:53:11.040 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve interface method 61271:
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso$RequestTransformer;.transformRequest
>   (Lcom/squareup/picasso/Request;)Lcom/squareup/picasso/Request; 04-18
>   09:53:11.040 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002 04-18 09:53:11.040
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef46 at 0x06 in Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18
>   09:53:11.040 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt:
>   unable to opt direct call 0xefbe at 0x1f in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18 09:53:11.040
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef2d at 0x2c in Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18
>   09:53:11.040 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt:
>   unable to opt direct call 0xef43 at 0x34 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef2e at 0x3c in Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18
>   09:53:11.050 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt:
>   unable to opt direct call 0xef20 at 0x44 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef3f at 0x4c in Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18
>   09:53:11.050 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt:
>   unable to optimize instance field ref 0x8505 at 0x54 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef45 at 0x56 in Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18
>   09:53:11.050 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt:
>   unable to opt direct call 0xef53 at 0x87 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;. 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize instance field ref 0x8504 at 0x2d in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.deliverAction 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize instance field ref 0x8504 at 0x55 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.deliverAction 04-18 09:53:11.050
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt
>   direct call 0xef81 at 0x02 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.cancelRequest 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize instance field ref 0x852f at 0x21 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.complete 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize static field ref 0x8518 at 0x13 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.resumeAction 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize instance field ref 0x8504 at 0x20 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.resumeAction 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize static field ref 0x8518 at 0x31 in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.resumeAction 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to
>   optimize instance field ref 0x8504 at 0x4a in
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso;.resumeAction 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm: Exception
>   Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing
>   Lcom/squareup/picasso/Picasso; 04-18 09:53:11.060
>   16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 04-18 09:53:11.060 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka W/dalvikvm:
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418b1c80)
>   04-18 09:53:11.080 16825-16825/com.kaaryanext.raghukaka
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.kaaryanext.raghukaka, PID: 16825 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1 at
>   com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.(Picasso.java:109) at
>   com.kaaryanext.raghukaka.listadapters.HomePageListAdapter$RecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(HomePageListAdapter.java:132)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try Following code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(base);
   }
}
```

and add following line in your android menifest file in application tag

```
android:name="your package name.MyApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following changes

1 In your Gradle you need to specify multi dex and add the support library:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  ...
}
```

2- In your manifest you have to set your application to a multidex application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.package.name">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="com.package.name.my_application">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.In your application class you have to either extend MultiDexApplication:

```
 public class my_application extends MultiDexApplication
{
  ...
 }
```

4.Or Overide the attachBaseContext() method:

```
public class my_application extends Application
{
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
    {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle Multiple dex file after enabling that option from `build.gradle`

& if in your project are you using Application class than extend it by with `MultiDexApplication` & handle multiple dex file in `attachBaseContext`

add this library in your dependencies

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //    your dependencies which you are using.

}
```

Your Application Class

```
public class MyAppClass extends MultiDexApplication{
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        MultiDex.install(newBase);
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    }
}
```

Declare `MyAppClass`  in your AndroidManfiest file application name.

```
<application
        android:name="MyAppClass"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
//... your other manifest declaration
</application>
```

***Updated gradle***

add this line in android defaultConfig

```
 multiDexEnabled true
```

**Suggestion**

Use only required play service library do not add entire Group of play service .